# virtualbox shared folder writing permission

Tags: mount, permissions, virtualbox

I am using virtualbox with host windows 10 and guest Ubuntu 16.04 .

I have a shared folder that I mount with: `sudo mount.vboxsf -o rw Documents_win ~/Shared/`

Everything is fine but then the mounted folder (Shared) has only reading permission.

How can I mount it in order to have writing permission as well?

EDIT:
These are the permission that I have on the folder:

```
luca@luca-VirtualBox:~$ ls -l
total 52
drwxr-xr-x 2 luca luca 4096 Oct 17 16:03 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 luca luca 4096 Oct 17 13:41 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 2 luca luca 4096 Oct 17 13:41 Downloads
-rw-r--r-- 1 luca luca 8980 Oct 17 13:36 examples.desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 luca luca 4096 Oct 17 13:41 Music
drwxrwxr-x 3 luca luca 4096 Oct 17 16:59 MyApps
drwxr-xr-x 2 luca luca 4096 Oct 17 13:41 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 2 luca luca 4096 Oct 17 13:41 Public
drwxrwxr-x 2 luca luca 4096 Oct 17 16:24 Shared
drwxr-xr-x 2 luca luca 4096 Oct 17 13:41 Templates
drwxr-xr-x 2 luca luca 4096 Oct 17 13:41 Videos
luca@luca-VirtualBox:~$ ls -l Shared/
total 0
```

Comment: What permissions and ownership do you have on the Shared folder? Cheers, Al

Comment: The folder Shared is in my home. These are the permission that I have from the guest OS.

Comment: Did you 1) install **guest additions**, 2) in settings/shared folder uncheck the **read only** in edit mode, 3) add yourself to the **vboxsf** group and logout/login? If one of these works, let me know and I'll put more detail in an answer. Cheers, Al